# how to make clickable buttons that add text into a div

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to create a function that adds text into an empty div depending on what button is clicked

i'm making a calculator as one of my beginner javascript projects (i know i can just use inputs and the "button" tag but i feel this'll be more original and challenging). i'm trying to add events to all the elements in the queryselector all nodelist, i feel my function is correct and i've tried all i can but the code doesn't seem to work, any help at all would be appreciated.

i am trying to create a kind of like input div that reflects the value or text of the clicked list item

```js
let digits = document.querySelectorAll("digit");
let add = document.getElementById("camper");

for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  digits[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    add.innerHTML += digits[i].innerHTML
  });
  digits[i].value = [i];
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="camper">
    <h3 id="insert"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3 id="equal">=</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="plus">+</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="minus">-</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="multiply">x</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="divide">\</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="write-box">
    <ul>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>1</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>2</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>3</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>4</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>5</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>6</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>7</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>8</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>9</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>0</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>clear</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>bkspc</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Start by giving the div the ID of camper instead of class

Comment: Then change document.querySelectorAll("digit"); to document.querySelectorAll(".digit");

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are losing the scope of `digits` inside the event listener. You need to bind `digits` to be the scope of `this` in the event listener like so:

```
let digits = document.querySelectorAll("digit");
let add = document.getElementById("camper");

for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  digits[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    add.innerHTML += this.innerHTML
  }).bind(digits[i]);
  digits[i].value = [i];
};
```

Comment: i cannot thank you enough i ran itho a bit of another problem though, for some weird reason only the "1" button or whatever shows inside the div when clicked the rest are just dormant. ok removed the bind method and it works fine now, again i cannot thank you enough its been driving me crazy

Comment: There is no need to bind at all. This works just fine too `let digits = document.querySelectorAll(".digit");
let add = document.getElementById("camper");

for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  digits[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    add.innerHTML += this.innerHTML
  });
};` and you are alos missing the dot in front of `digit` in your selector

Answer (score 0):

**Typos**

- it is `id="camper"` and not `class="camper"` if you want to use getElementById but you likely want `insert` instead of `camper`
- it is `querySelectorAll(".digit")` - you are missing the dot in the class selector

**Logic**

- use `this.innerText` to get the content of the digit

```js
let digits = document.querySelectorAll(".digit");
let add = document.getElementById("insert");

for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
  digits[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    add.innerHTML += this.innerText;
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="camper">
    <h3 id="insert"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3 id="equal">=</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="plus">+</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="minus">-</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="multiply">x</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3 id="divide">\</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="write-box">
    <ul>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>1</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>2</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>3</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>4</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>5</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>6</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>7</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>8</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>9</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>0</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>clear</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>bkspc</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a more elegant way - if you are doing homework, you might want to do more coding before looking :)

```js
let add = document.getElementById("insert");

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName==="H3") {
    const text = tgt.innerText;
    const cn = tgt.parentNode.className;
    if (cn === "digit" || cn === "oper") add.innerText += text;
    else if (cn==="action") {
      if (text === "clear") {
        add.innerText = "";
      }  
      else if (text === "bkspc") {
        add.innerText = add.innerText.slice(0,-1);
      }  
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="camper">
    <h2 id="insert"></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right-box">
    <ul>
      <li class="oper">
        <h3 id="equal">=</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oper">
        <h3 id="plus">+</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oper">
        <h3 id="minus">-</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oper">
        <h3 id="multiply">x</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="oper">
        <h3 id="divide">\</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="write-box">
    <ul>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>1</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>2</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>3</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>4</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>5</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>6</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>7</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>8</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>9</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="digit">
        <h3>0</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="action">
        <h3>clear</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="action">
        <h3>bkspc</h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```